# Как правильно использовать fancybox в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, fancybox

Всем привет! Может кто подскажет, использую фреймворк alethemes, post-type gallery как правильно вывести галерею изображений чтобы при нажатии на картинку работал fancybox? Сам fancybox подключил css и js, класс fancybox на ссылку задал, в script.js прописал чтобы при нажатии на ссылку срабатывал fancybox, но не знаю как правильно написать в параметр href значение, чтобы генерировалось правильно ссылка на большое изображение. Получается если оставляю параметр пустым, то все срабатывает и картинка открывается в модальном окне, но при сворачивании она пропадает со страницы.

```
<div class="gallery_items">
                <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => null,
                    'order'             => 'ASC',
                    'orderby'           => 'menu_order ID',
                    'meta_query'        => array(
                        array(
                            'key'       => '_ale_hide_from_gallery',
                            'value'     => 0,
                            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID
                );
                $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                if ( $attachments ) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>
                        <div class="single">
                            <a class="fancybox" href=""><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'gallery-big' ); ?></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php }
                } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: в href wp_get_attachment_url( $id )

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! только немного изменил на: href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось, спасибо! только немного изменил на: `href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?>"`

Comment: Это не ответ, исправьте, чтобы был полноценный ответ, либо удалите.

Answer (score 1):

В href нужно указать ресурс, картинки отображаемой в попапе:
для WP это: `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'gallery-big')` 
a внутри тегов ссылки картинку или текст, например: `wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id,'thumbnail')`, при нажатии на который появляется всплывающее окно с источником(картинка/видео)

Comment: Странно, если указываю wp_get_attachment_image_src, то открывается эта картинка в новом окне. А вот с wp_get_attachment_url получилось добиться нужного эффекта. ХЗ почему так, может это особенность фреймворка?!